# Robot framework can find xpath location on Wikipedia search bar

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework

Im trying to do some simple task on Wikipedia page where I want to input search text on Wikipedia main page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)

```
xpath=//form[@id='searchform']//input[@role='combobox']
```

[image]

However, Robot Framework keeps telling me that its element is not found.

```
  Element with locator 'xapth=//form[@id='searchform']//input[@role='combobox']' not found.
```

Did I miss something on the xpath locator? Could someone please assist me on this.

Many thanks

Comment: I found the XPATH to be //form[@id='searchform']//input[@type='search'] 

FYI: I'm using Google Chrome 119.0.6045.159, fully maximized on a Windows 11 operating system. Not all browsers may have the 'combobox' attribute like your's. Instead, I would recommend searching by the input's type since we know that it has to be a search type input regardless of the browser it's presented in. Cheers!

Comment: It seems it's just a typo in your code. The `xapth=` should be `xpath=`.